# PouchDB local storage with Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, local-storage, pouchdb

I use PouchDB to synchronize a local storage database with a remote CouchDB database.

In Chrome, I can see the content of the local storage slots (WebSQL, IndexedDB...) with [PourchDB Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pouchdb-inspector/hbhhpaojmpfimakffndmpmpndcmonkfa) (add-on for Chrome) or with the tab Ressources in the developer tools:

[image]

Do you know if it is possible to get the content of local storage in the Android Webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well you would like to use chrome debug tools on an Android device? if so maybe that link can help you : 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews